# 500 Internal Server Error on Cloudflare Page

Tags: next.js, cloudflare, vercel, http-status-code-500, cloudflare-pages

I got this error after deploying a Next.js project on the Cloudflare Page. With the same source code, it works fine on Netlify and Vercel.
This is the source code: https://github.com/viswaah/vercel-redirect
[image]

Please let me know how to fix it.
Thanks so much!

Comment: Repo is 2+ years old apart from a minor commit. Create an issue and/or check the forks, perhaps someone already ran into the problem and has a fix.